# rotation vector

Tags: differential-geometry

If $t(t),n(t),b(t)$ are rotating, right-handed frame of orthogonal unit vectors. Show that there exists a vector $w(t)$ (the rotation vector) such that
$\dot{t} = w \times t$, 
$\dot{n} = w \times n$, and
$\dot{b} = w \times b$

So I'm thinking this is related to Frenet-Serret Equations and that the matrix of coefficient for $\dot{t}, \dot{n}, \dot{b}$ with respect to $t,n,b$ is skew-symmetric.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have sufficient information to compute it yourself! :)

Suppose that $w=aT+bN+cB$, with $a$, $b$ and $c$ some functions. Then you want, for example, that $$\kappa N = T' = w\times T = (aT+bN+cB)\times T=b N\times T+cB\times T=-bB+cN.$$ Since $\{T,N,B\}$ is an basis, this gives you some information about the coefficients. Can you finish?

Comment: @ Mariano: I'm not very familiar with linear algebra. What does basis have to do with the coefficients?

Comment: @LindsayDuran, you should really familiarize yourself with linear algebra: explaining this is a bit outside of the scope of comments!

Comment: @Mariano: I got $\omega$ in terms of $\tau$ and $\kappa$, but the problem didnt specify a curve. How should I deal with this?

Comment: @ninja: That's fine, as both curvature and torsion should indeed be involved. What else were you expecting?